# Is it possible to get the current machine name in IIS 7.5 Url Rewrite Module Rules?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

The HTTP_HOST and SERVER_NAME server variables give me the host name from the HTTP request (which can be an IP address or the load-balanced DNS based on how the request was made). I could not find a server variable that will give me actual machine name (i.e., the value of the COMPUTERNAME environment variable).

I am trying to set-up some redirection rules on a server-farm and there are some rules based on what the current machine name is (e.g., internal machines have `int` in their name). I don't want to create separate rules for each machine, and instead want to have some conditional logic based on the current machine name. I cannot seem to find a way to get hold of the machine name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IIS7 The computer name isn't one of the built-in server variables. However all is not lost, with a bit of work using a custom UrlRewrite provider you can surface your machine name in a rewrite rule.

Scott Forsyth has actually built something like this already and has written a blog post describing its use, and provided the source and a pre-built binary + installer:

> [URLRewrite ServerNameVariable Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/04/02/urlrewrite-servernamevariable-provider.aspx)

For the sake of preserving this information in the event of that article disappearing here are loosely the steps:

Start by creating a new class library project in Visual Studio. You can find the steps to do this here:

> [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module (IIS.NET)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/)

They are in essence (in case the link dies):

1. Create a Class Library project and call it something like `ServerNameProvider`. *You need to make sure the project is a .NET 2.0 or 3.5 project. IIS7.5 managed code support still targets the 2.0 runtime.*
2. Rename the default `Class1.cs` file to a name that reflects the provider purpose, for example: `ServerName.cs` - and just make sure the class name in the source reflects this as well.
3. Add a reference to:  `%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\IIS\Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.dll`.
4. In the project properties create a strong name key (on the signing tab)
5. Add a post-build event to install the provider assembly in your dev PC GAC (just for testing):

   ```
   CALL "%VS90COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat" > NULL 
   gacutil.exe /if "$(TargetPath)"
   ```

   Note, if using Visual Studio 2010 then the environment variable `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` should be changed to `%VS100COMNTOOLS%`.
6. Open up the `ServerName.cs` file and make sure your class implements the `Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.IRewriteProvider` interface:

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite;

   namespace ServerNameVariable
   {
     public class ServerName : IRewriteProvider
     {
       public void Initialize(IDictionary<string, string> settings, 
                          IRewriteContext rewriteContext)
       {
       }

       public string Rewrite(string value)
       {
         return  System.Environment.MachineName;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
7. Build the project. On your local PC the assembly will be installed into the GAC.
8. Register the provider with IIS:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/providers /+"[name='ServerNameVariable',type='ServerNameVariable.ServerName, ServerNameVariable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5854ff76fb5c07af']" /commit:apphost
```

Make sure the `PublicKeyToken` value in the command line above matches your assembly's public key token. You can extract that value by doing `sn.exe -T <assemblyfile.dll>`, for example:

```
e:\AppDev\..bin\Debug> sn.exe -T ServerNameVariable.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is 5854ff76fb5c07af
```

The next thing to do is use your new provider in a rewrite rule, for example, here's the example Scott gave which is an outbound rule:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Set Custom Header" enabled="true">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X_Machine_Name" pattern=".*" />
         <action type="Rewrite" value="{ServerNameVariable:}" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

And here's a simple inbound rule that redirects to google.com if the machine name is `BOB`:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="TestServerVariableProvider" 
              enabled="true" 
              stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{ServerNameVariable:}" pattern="BOB" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" 
                    url="http://google.com" 
                    appendQueryString="false" 
                    redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```